# php urldecode without keys in a multidimensional array

Tags: php

after using `urldecode`:

I get a query string like this:

```
type[0]=1&type[1]=2
```

the problem is that I can't remove the keys, so what I want is this:

```
type[]=1&type[]=2
```

a query string without indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pre_replace` to remove indexes.

Snippet

```
$qryStr = 'type[0]=1&type[1]=2';
$result = preg_replace('/\[(\d+)\]/', '[]', $qryStr);
echo $result;
```

Output

```
type[]=1&type[]=2
```

Live [demo](https://3v4l.org/g0jhL)

Bonus: If indexs are associative keys then replace `\d+` with `\w+`

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)